# TimeZones in specific format

Tags: iphone

I am new to the concept of TimeZone in iphone.I have struck with small doubt,how can we get all the timezones in the iphone device in the format of (GMT +5:30) Bombay,Calcutta,Madras,New Delhi.
I am trying this by using the api [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames] and place it in an array but it shows in different format but i want the above format.can you please help any body if you know this..

Comment: You can also post your some code here for nice and good help.

Answer (score 0):

Dude use my code as i shown below. It's need some workaround but you will get what you want.

```
     NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc]init];
     temp = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];
     for (id tstring in temp)
     {
         NSString *tstring2 = [[NSString alloc]init];
         tstring2 =  tstring;
         NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
         NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
         [df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
         [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:tstring2]];
         NSString *alltime = [df stringFromDate:now];
          NSLog(@"%@ %@",tstring2, alltime);
         [tstring2 release];

     }
```

**>> OutPut**
 You will get country data but here i post for some of them only

```
     Asia/Katmandu 4:21:21 PM GMT+05:45
     Asia/Kolkata 4:06:21 PM GMT+05:30
     Asia/Krasnoyarsk 6:36:21 PM GMT
     America/Tortola 6:36:21 AM AST
     America/Vancouver 3:36:21 AM PDT
     America/Whitehorse 3:36:21 AM PDT
     Europe/Copenhagen 12:36:21 PM GMT+02:00
     Europe/Dublin 11:36:21 AM GMT+01:00
     Europe/Gibraltar 12:36:21 PM GMT
```

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: See my and and let me know if you find any difficulty...enjoy..:)